# Is Jeremiah 18:2 grammatically incorrect?

Tags: hebrew, grammar, jeremiah

This may seem like an insignificant question but I was wondering why the Hebrew "וְשָׁ֖מָּה" which is feminine appears in Jeremiah 18:2 to refer to "בֵּ֣ית" which is masculine:

> קוּם וְיָרַדְתָּ בֵּית הַיּוֹצֵר; וְשָׁמָּה, אַשְׁמִיעֲךָ
>   אֶת-דְּבָרָי

Comment: I think v~shm-e is an adverb that is translated "and~there~ward" in that verse. "shm" being Strong's 8033: there/thither. The hey is sometimes directional, as in 'north~ward'.

Comment: @tblue Thank you for your input.

Comment: Seconding the suffix *-ah* meaning "in the direction of". Also used of specific places like *beitah* "homeward" and *yerushalaimah* "to Jerusalem".

Comment: @Luke Sawczak Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

To make tblue's comment into an answer:

What you see in [Jeremiah 18:2](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/jeremiah/18-2.htm) isn't a feminine ending, but a suffixed ה *ah* on the word [שָׁמ](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/8033.htm) *sham* "there".

This suffix can be loosely translated as either direction (towards X) or distance (over at X). For example, the word יְרוּשָׁלַם *yerushala(i)m* is suffixed to become יְרוּשָׁלַיְמָה *yerushalaim**ah*** when Sennacherib sends his servants "**to** Jerusalem" in [2 Chronicles 32:9](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/2_chronicles/32-9.htm). Other examples are "northward" and "homeward".

In this instance, the sense of direction stems from the command to travel to the potter's house. (You might expect בֵּית *beit* "house" to have the same suffix, but it can't because it's bound to the word "potter".) I would probably capture that sense in translation as "over there" or, more dynamically, "once you're there".

Note that the Bible does have grammatical inconsistencies elsewhere, so it's a valid question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.